# how to limit scope of overloaded new/delete operator to translation unit only (when they can not be made static)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

While moving the project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017 I am facing a problem. One of the projects has global static overloaded new/delete operators, on compiling with VS2017 it throws an error that new/delete operators can not be declared static (it used to compile on VS2010). But static ensures scope of these overloaded new/delete specific to a translation unit. 
How this can be achieved when no more static new/delete operators are allowed.
Please help me with the suggestions.

Comment: Define the operators in the cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

provide both declaration and definition inside a CPP file. This will limit the visibility to specific compilation unit

Comment: thanks for the reply. Then do I have to declare and define these new/delete functions in all the CPP files where the earlier header was getting included?

Comment: I hope you wanted to use the overloaded new/delete for a particular class, then make it a member of the class

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Actually I want to use it for a project which has multiple classes. And this project is a part of a bigger project (consisting of multiple projects).

Answer (score 0):

When you overload new/delete operator, they are implicitly static and no scope resolution required to construct the object. You can visit the [web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875228/why-overloaded-new-operator-is-implicitly-static-and-no-scope-resolution-require) to know why.

The `new` and `delete` operators can also be overloaded like other operators in C++. `new` and `delete` operators can be overloaded globally or they can be overloaded for specific classes.
If these operators are overloaded using member function for a class, it means that these operators are overloaded only for that specific class.
If overloading is done outside a class (i.e. it is not a member function of a class), the overloaded `new` and `delete` will be called anytime you make use of these operators (within classes or outside classes). This is global overloading.

So, you don’t need to declare and define these new/delete functions in all the CPP files where the earlier header was getting included.