# Why can't use placement new if I overrride operator new?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I think there may be an exsiting implemented `void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)` for it.
Is this true?

gcc version 8.1.0

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <new>

class Base {
public:
    char c = 'a';
    int i = 42;

    // can't use placement new if this function exists
    void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Base::new()" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "param size: " << size << std::endl; // 8. actual size of Base instance
        return malloc(size);
    }
};



int main()
{
    char buff[100];
    Base* b1 = new Base;
    Base* b2 = new ((void*)buff) Base; // error: no matching function for call to 'Base::operator new(sizetype, void*)'
    std::cout << buff[0] << std::endl; // a
    std::cout << *((int*)&buff[4]) << std::endl; // 42

    delete b1;
    b2->~Base();
    return 0;
}
```

I searched on the Internet and asked ChatGPT, both got nothing.

Comment: The "why" is basically answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875313/3966456)

Comment: If you provide a `new` function, the compiler will not generate the other implicitly static `new` functions.  You'll need to provide a placement `new`, if you want that to be available.  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: It pretty much follows the normal overload resolution rules; once the name of the allocation function (i.e. `operator new`) is found in the class scope, the lookup procedure stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid (I believe) selecting the wrong overload of `new`, you need to do:

```
Base* b2 = ::new ((void*) buff) Base;
```

Also, if you provide your own `operator new`, you need to provide a corresponding implementation for `operator delete` (not done in my example):

https://wandbox.org/permlink/eMrZxd7epzF6KHUk

Output:

```
Base::new()
param size: 8
42
```